# How to set a watchpoint but not actually break (only print values) (Xcode)

Tags: xcode, lldb

I have read the tutorial about watchpoints here http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html

I'm able to set a watchpoint in lldb/Xcode

```
watch set var name
```

and I get the output of the format:

```
Watchpoint 2 hit:
old value: 130
new value: 130
```

My question is can I not break and only see those values getting printed similar to the feature `"Automatically continue after evaluating actions"` in Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

```
(lldb) watchpoint command add -o continue [<watchpoint_number>]
```

If you don't specify the watchpoint number, it will add the command to the last set watchpoint.